# Mouse Events on SVG rect

Tags: javascript, html, svg, mouseevent, dom-events

I am trying to show tooltip in JavaScript inside an SVG rect for MouseDown and mousemove events in a rect area.
Problem is: I am not able to capture events at every mouse move and mouse down operation.
Below is my sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <script src=jquery-2.0.2.js></script>
        <script>
            onMouseDown = function ( evt ) {
                evt.preventDefault();
                var tooltip = document.getElementById( 'tooltip' );
                tooltip.setAttribute( 'visibility', 'visible' );
                tooltip.setAttribute( 'x', evt.x );
                tooltip.setAttribute( 'y', evt.y );
            };

            onMouseMove = function ( evt ) {
                evt.preventDefault();
                var tooltip = document.getElementById( 'tooltip' );
                tooltip.setAttribute( 'visibility', 'visible' );
                tooltip.setAttribute( 'x', evt.x );
                tooltip.setAttribute( 'y', evt.y );
            };
        </script>
```

Comment: Could you pop an example on a jsfiddle.

Comment: Missing `$(some-svg-element).on( "mousedown", onMouseDown)`